Ошибка шины (стек памяти сбронеш на диск) (angular)
Ребят, помогите. В терминал пишу команду ng serve, а мне выдает Ошибка шины (стек памяти сброшен на диск). Работаю с Angular на Ubuntu.

Вопрос решен, у меня просто была удалена версия nodeJs с которой работал сам проект. Переустановил нужную версию NodeJs и все заработало.
